# how to search for blank lines in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to create an if statement that performs an action when it reads a blank line.
I would assume it would be something like this :  if ($line=='\n');then
where line is the line that it is reading from a text file. But this is not working.

Comment: It’s not working because `read` (which I assume you are using) does not include the newline into its output. A blank line is thus exactly that, an empty string, for which `bash` provides the `-z` operator: `[[ -z $REPLY ]] && # processing here`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line; do
    if [ "$line" = "" ]; then
         echo BLANK
    fi
done < filename.txt
```

or a slight variation:

```
while read line; do
    if [ "$line" ]; then
         echo NOT BLANK
    else
         echo BLANK
    fi
done < filename.txt
```

Comment: @chepner - Thanks for the improvement.

Comment: There's also the `-n` and `-z` conditional operators for "not empty" and "empty" respectively. (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

Comment: Note that you should be unsetting `IFS` for your `read`, otherwise, lines that contain whitespace will be shown as BLANK (which, I'm assuming is not desired behavior).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if [[ "x$line" == "x" ]]; then...
```

or

```
if [[ "$line" =~ "^$" ]]; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or also:

```
grep -q '.' <<< $line
```

Returns 1 if `line` is empty, 0 if non-empty